# How to disable populating enclosing namespaces with c++ inline namespaces in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen, inline-namespaces

Is there a way to disable adding inline namespaces to their enclosing namespaces in doxygen?

- *F.e.*
  Running the [test example 57](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/61f8521f768165e02a5f28df3fb442e3b91d170b/testing/057_inlinenamespace.cpp) with a vanilla Doxyfile created with the wizard the following class list is produced

[image]

I'm looking for a way to disable library::v2::foo from being listed under library as well:

[image]

I'd prefer a [configuration option](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html) but a [special command](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html), [some sort of grouping](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/grouping.html) or any other solution would also be ok.

Here's the [source code for the test 57](https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/blob/61f8521f768165e02a5f28df3fb442e3b91d170b/testing/057_inlinenamespace.cpp):

```
namespace library
{
    namespace v1
    {
        class foo { public: void member(); };
        void func();
        namespace NS {}
    }
    inline namespace v2
    {
        class foo { public: void member(); };
        void func();
        namespace NS {}
    }
}
```

Comment: The members of an inline namespace are accessible through their owning namespace. Also, for most uses of inline namespaces, code external to the system is not *supposed* to know about or use the inline namespace. They're supposed to access those names through the namespace they're inlined into. So Doxygen is apparently doing the right thing here.